# Memory leak at performSelectorOnMainThread

Tags: iphone, multithreading, memory-management, memory-leaks

I am running into some issues with the memory management on my app. The app will run properly for a while, then I will get a **Received memory warning** error. I then ran my app through Profile to find the memory leaks. After tracking the leaks, I got a 100% memory leak on this line:

```
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(loadingProgress:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0] waitUntilDone:NO];
```

I may be naive, but I didn't know that this could leak...

Anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: could you tell what to did to solve the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only possible leak is if you are over-retaining the `NSNumber` instance in your thread.  But for that to cause a crash, you'd have to be spinning off thousands and thousands of threads, indicating a very serious problem in and of itself.

Note that the Leaks instrument shows you where the leak was allocated, not where it might have been over-retained.

Likewise, leaks only shows, well, leaks.  It won't show accretion of allocations where the allocations are still referenced by the global object graph.  I.e. if an object is reachable by a reference path starting at a global variable, then it isn't a leak.

Try [heapshot analysis](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2010/10/17/when-is-a-leak-not-a-leak-using-heapshot-analysis-to-find-undesirable-memory-growth/).  It is very good at finding this kind of accretion over time.